# Laravel can't detect environment variables set by Forge when run from console

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

For instance, if I set the environment variable `DB_HOST` with value `localhost` through Forge, it creates an entry in the nginx file of `fastcgi_param DB_HOST "localhost";`

When I enter the console and try to run any command, any command that depends on that environment variable returns false if I do `getenv('DB_HOST')`.

However, if I run the site from the browser, there is no problem. Only the console app seems to have this issue.

What is erasing the contents of the environment variables, or preventing them from being read, when in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to keep the environment variables in one place (the nginx config file) but there is a workaround of creating a `.env.php` file in your app root dir, which makes them available for production.

To do this, I added the following to my `.env.php` file:

```
return [
    'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
    'DB_NAME' => 'thename',
    'DB_USER' => 'theuser',
    'DB_PASS' => 'thepass'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're running from the command line, no environment is set as those are for the HTTPD. Console requests do not go through nginx, just PHP.

You can set the environment for the command you're running, with the `--env` option. Example:

```
php artisan migrate --env=develop
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well. Didn't work. I still get empty results from the environment variables from any Artisan commands that depend on them. I also tried adding them to a `config/.env.php` file, but no luck.

Comment: I did just realize that this workaround was wrong. I should have put .env.php into the app root dir, not the config dir.